# Beginner: VM Instances Can't Access External Network And Few Other Questions

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, kolla-ansible

I was trying to deploy a multinode OpenStack cloud using Kolla-Ansible by following this doc and many others:
https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/kolla-ansible/2023.1/multinode.html. I want to clarify here that I'm very new in OpenStack and hoping to get some guidance from the pros.

The nodes comprise 1 Kolla node, 1 control node, 1 compute node, and 1 storage node. All the nodes are VMs hosted on a VMware vSphere cluster. Each of the nodes has 2 NICs both connected to the same port group e.g. VLAN 100. Except for the Kolla node which only has one NIC and is connected to VLAN 100 port group also. All the nodes are running Rocky Linux 9.

The subnet for VLAN 100 is `10.0.32/0` which has a gateway on an external firewall `10.0.32.1`. So for each of the nodes, I use the first NIC (ens192) as the `network_interface` and `api_interface` configured in the `globals.yml` file. Meanwhile, the second NIC (ens224) is used for `neutron_external_interface`.

I've set up a test environment using the `init-runonce` script and I modified the info in `EXT_NET_CIDR` to use `10.0.32.0/20` as the external network. The script created 1 virtual router named `demo-router`,1 network named `demo-net`, and 1 instance named `demo1`. After that, I created 1 new instance, `demo2`, 1 new network named `demo-net1`, and connected it to the same virtual router. Both instances can ping each other from different subnets/networks.
[Instances image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj65q.png), [Network Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcNBC.png), [Ping Test from demo1 to demo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGM82.png)

However, I can't seems to able to ping something on the Internet e.g. `1.1.1.1` or even the external gateway `10.0.32.1`. [Ping from demo1 to Internet and external gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEzVP.png). I've included my multimode inventory and the `globals.yml` config snippet below.

```
# multinode config file

[control]
control-node1

[Network]
control-node1

[compute]
compute-node1

[Monitoring]
control-node1

[Storage]
storage-node1

[deployment]
localhost       ansible_connection=local
```

```
# /etc/kolla/globals.yml file

kolla_base_distro: "rocky"

network_interface: "ens192"
api_interface: "ens192"
neutron_external_interface: "ens224"

enable_openstack_core: "yes"
enable_neutron: "{{ enable_openstack_core | bool }}"
neutron_plugin_agent: "open switch"
enable_openvswitch: "{{ enable_neutron | bool and neutron_plugin_agent != 'Linux bridge' }}"
```

On another note, I have a few questions regarding network interfaces and storage.

1. Is it possible to use separate physical NIC on the node for management, external, storage, and live migration traffic? I know that `neutron_external_interface` is for the external NIC and `api_interface` is for the management NIC. What about storage and live migration? Is there a way I can set it in Kolla Ansible?
2. I've configured a storage node, `storage-node1`, and enabled Cinder with the LVM backend.

```
enable_cinder: "Yes"
enable_cinder_backend_lvm: "Yes"
```

How can I use it as the storage for Nova VM instead of the compute node local disk?

Thanks all for the help and suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

[@Muhammad](https://serverfault.com/users/1028794/muhammad-hanis-irfan-mohd-zaid)

Did you end up figuring out this?

> How can I use it as the storage for Nova VM instead of the compute node local disk?

I'm doing the same currently, and when I provision an instance, it creates the disk on the storage node but the instance fails to attach it to be able to boot.  My thought was that it was going to use the management adapter but I see iSCSI errors.

Comment: Nope I don't. I've ended up abandoning this and go for another virtualization solution. I know this a bit too late but I hope yours are working now.